# Amazon Web Services and Github integration?

Tags: github, amazon-web-services

I would like to deploy a branch of a project on my github.com account to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I would adore being able to use a GUI.

Is there such a thing for AWS? Will I have to use the AWS command line tools? :-(

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: If you are using Elastic Beanstalk you should absolutely not be making changes on the instance itself outside of Beanstalk.  If Beanstalk ever recovers your instance, auto heals or scales at all, the changes will not propagate and will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an EBS volume using the web API and then use something akin to [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) or [RedMine](http://www.redmine.org) to view the repository.